# Not yet supported place for UDAF 'count' in CASE statments

Tags: sql, hive

When I execute the below query, I get the error "count" is not supported in case statements. Wondering whether there is a work around for this.

```
    select 
    sum(case when a.key1 == 80 then count(distinct a.key2) else 0 end) as no_80_counts,
    from table1
```

Comment: nesting aggregate functions isn't supported. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: For a specific key1 value, I am trying to count the distinct key2's as a key1 can be associated with more than one key2's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nesting aggregate functions isn't supported. You're overthinking it.

```
select count(distinct key2) as no_80_counts,
from table1
where key1 = 80
```

or

```
select count(distinct case when key1=80 then key2 end) as no_80_counts,
from table1
```

Remove the `where` clause and `group by key1` to get distinct key2 counts for all key1.